# using hdmi and vga on pc for extending windows

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, computer-building

I am building a new pc.
There is a situation I need to handle. Here I am going with the R7 240 2GB DDR3 XFX card which has both HDMI and VGA outs.
I have an old monitor HP w15e which has only VGA port.
I am going to get a new monitor 1080p which is DELL-SE2216H and has both HDMI and VGA connection.

problem: I will use dell as primary monitor and hp as secondary using "extend display" feature on windows 10. I am thinking of connecting dell using HDMI and hp using VGA. Can i use both HDMI and VGA at the same time to extend the screen?

So on the desktop
HDMI from gfx card-->dell 1080p 
VGA from gfx card-->hp 720p

how can I be sure before buying the thing?

thanks.

PS: the parts link https://in.pcpartpicker.com/list/CJgxzM, didn't get exact model for hp w15e so it shows hp w185e

Comment: The R7 240 has the ability to use both it's ports at the same time though.

Comment: @Ramhound, so in theory, i should be able to use HDMI for Dell and VGA for hp and extend the windows screen and not just clone it? Will I need a GDDR5 card like RX 550 or this one will get the job done? Thanks

Comment: I will not make any hardware recommendations here at Superuser.  Do your research and purchase the hardware that best fits your requirements.

Comment: @Ramhound uhm ok, but how to know what is sufficient?

Comment: You are buying 14 year old hardware.  I wouldn't purchase a R7 240.  The majority of AAA games, require at least 3GB VRAM, evenv at their lowest settings in 2017.  The amount of games that will be able to run on 2GB of VRAM will be the minority.

Comment: @Ramhound ryzen cpus dont come with iGpu so i thought about putting a cheap one.

Comment: So do your research and based on your requirements for the PC purchase an acceptable GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound btw wiki shows R7 was released in 2013 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Rx_200_series

Comment: You indicated you were going to purchase a 2GB R7 240, [MSI AMD Radeon R7 240 2GB DDR3 VGA/DVI/HDMI Low Profile P(CI-Express Video Card](https://www.amazon.com/MSI-R7-240-Profile-PCI-Express/dp/B00FRHIIPK), Amazon started to have that particular card in stock in 2004.  *Even with a release date of 2014, I still wouldn't purchase it, because it's 4 year old hardware*  This opinionated response is the exact reason hardware recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser.  Which is precisely the reason I attempted to avoid answering your required for a hardware recommendation.

Comment: @Ramhound The pc partpicker shows the product as https://in.pcpartpicker.com/product/7RQypg/xfx-video-card-r7240aclf2
didn't know that was ancient thing,Thanks

Comment: Looks like Amazon has an incorrect date.  I have blocked that particular website.